# Weblogic Threads Usage

Tags: performance, weblogic, threads

I have an application deployed on WebLogic 10.3, which exhibits a strange behavior.

- I am running a constant (not too high) load on my application (20 concurrent users, running a light activity).
- The response time is reasonable (well below 100ms after the application stabilizes)
- Memory consumption seems fine (My application creates a lot of short-living objects, but they are garbaged collected so the overall memory consumption stays under 500 mb).
- Threads stats seem healthy as well:
  [image: Thread Pool]

And yet, after I leave my test running for a while, more and more execute threads ("[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'") are created, until eventually the application crashes:
[image: Threads Creation]

This test hasn't been running for a long time (All the new threads that you don't see in the first screenshot were created while I was writing this question), and I've seen much more threads being created.

Any idea why these threads are being created?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you analyze these by taking a thread dump, so you can see what they're doing before they crash.

Take 4 or 5 sets of thread dumps at an interval of 5 seconds between each. so at the end you will have a single log file which has around 20 - 25 seconds worth of action on the app server.

Then run these through [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) or TDA (I havent used TDA myself), it will highlight those in Red colour so you can quickly click on it and get to the lines showing issues.

See an example of [this here](http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/01/app-server-high-cpu-or-low-threads.html). Look at the Samurai output image in that link. Green is fine. Red and grey need looking at.